# cp command does not work on Android 4.4

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I am facing a weird behavior on Android 4.4.
The command below works perfectly on android Jelly Bean rooted device:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());

// path is a folder saved on sdcard
dos.writeBytes("cp -a " + path + " " + "/data/data" + " \n");
dos.flush();
process.waitFor() return 0 mean Ok
```

However on Android 4.4 rooted device, the above commands does not work.
    process.waitFor() return 1 mean there is error somewhere.

I notice that when running on Android Jelly Bean rooted device, the permission for files are: rwxr-x.
On Android 4.4 rooted, they are: rwxrwx--

I googled this problem but did not find any result so far.
Thanks. :)

UPDATE:
I can copy data from /data/data folder using cp command to sdcard folder.

Comment: why not just use `su -c cp ....` in your `exec` ?

Comment: Actually, It does not only exec the cp command, also a bunch of command after that.

Comment: Wrap it with a try catch block

Comment: Yes, I did, as I said that the above code works perfectly on Android Jelly Bean rooted.

Comment: Don't make assumptions about where things are, and don't expect hacks like this to keep working.  If you want to figure out why ut is failing this time, use a terminal or sshd app and try the iperatiins manually (but don't use adb - that is an increasingly different environment from what an app gets).

Comment: Have you tried something like: `Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su root cp -a " + path + " " + "/data/data")`.

Comment: @ChuongPham: I tried your command but Its still return 1 (mean error).

Comment: @Dat: Maybe try to copy just one file to see if you get the same result. Or, have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work by changing the command.

```
cp -a " + path + " " + "/data/data" + " \n"
```

to

```
cp -r " + path + " " + "/data/data" + " \n"
```

The difference between -a and -r is, -a will remain all the permission of the copying files that I dont know why it does not work on android 4.4. -r will also copy all the files and folders but it changes the permission of file, the simple solution (I think) is to chmod the permission manually after copying.

Answer (score 1):

Before running `su` on Android 4.4+ to copy/write files in a rooted device, make a backup of this file:

`/system/etc/permissions/platform.xml`

Then see if the following permission and groups have been defined in `platform.xml`:

```
<permission name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
    <group gid="sdcard_r" />
    <group gid="sdcard_rw" />
    <group gid="media_rw" />
</permission>
```

If not, edit `platform.xml` and add them, save, then reboot your device and try your `su` command again.

*If all else fail, try to install the `BusyBox` binary on the rooted device and run the `su` command through it.*

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I manage to make it work by changing the option of the cp from -a to -r, then I chmod all the folders manually.

Comment: @Dat: No problem. Glad you've solved it yourself. Can you answer your own question, then wait 24 hours and accept your own answer. This way, your post will moved off the Unanswered queue. Note: You have to wait 24 hour before you can accept your own answer.